# Trying to create a MYSQL if else query with trigger where the temperature gets recorded on another table

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, database-trigger, datatrigger

I've been trying to implement this query where if someone inserts temperature above 37.5 it will get recorded to another table automatically through a trigger. But I've been getting errors with this one. Here checkpoint and TableB are two tables.

```
    AFTER INSERT ON checkpoint
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    IF (checkpoint.temperature>"37.5")
    THEN
      UPDATE TableB
      SET temp2 = NEW.checkpoint_temperature,
      WHERE ID = NEW.ID,
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: what is your error-message?

Comment: I don't see the create statement and since you have more than 1 statement in the trigger I would expect to see delimiter being set and why the quotes "37.5" and WHERE ID = NEW.ID, has a comma at the end which should be semi colon (;) and why does the set statement have a comma at the end??